# How to find the factor which is more contributing to an event

Tags: modeling, deterministic

I have two datasets. 
Dataset#1 consists of information of patients having one of the three diseases and the hospital they are  treated. Each patient will have only one disease.

```
Dataset 1:
Patient_id, Disease, Hospital
1, D_A, H_A
2, D_A, H_A
3, D_A, H_A
4, D_B, H_A
5, D_C, H_A
6, D_A, H_B
7, D_B, H_C
8, D_C, H_C
```

Second dataset has the death rate in the hospital caused by all of these three diseases. (Unfortunately no death rates are available for individual diseases)

```
Dataset 2
Hospital, Death per 1000
H_A, 12
H_B, 17
H_C, 22
```

I want to find out which of these three diseases causing more death assuming all the other factors influencing the death rate are constant. Can someone please help me to model this.

Comment: You will need to make strong assumptions, such as that the diseases have the same death rate in each hospital.  You cannot hope to estimate individual disease death rates by hospital. It would also help to have more basic data such as *total deaths* in each hospital rather than just the death rates. This is because a death rate of 10 per 1000 means something different when it is based on observing one death in 100 patients compared to observing 10,000 deaths among a million patients.

Comment: Thanks Whuber, Yes It can be assumed that the each diseases have the same death rate in each of the hospitals. I have the data of total deaths in each hospital as well. Is this a linear regression problem ?

Comment: Yes (assuming your disease dataset is complete), but because these death rates are based on counts of relatively rare occurrences, the method to consider is Poisson regression rather than Ordinary Least Squares regression.

Comment: Actually the Dataset#1, i.e disease type, the patient id and the hospital treated, is a random sample. But the total count of death and death rate in each of these hospitals due to these 3 diseases is a complete data set.  
The number of patients treated in each hospitals largely vary. So is it still fine to use the death count in the model.